# How to use cgo in Goclipse with Mingw?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, mingw, go, cgo

When i try to use cgo I get the error

exec gcc: exec: "gcc": executable file not found in %PATH%

I have Mingw installed. How do I tell Goclipse where gcc is? I could not find a way in preferences or properties to set this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the path to MinGW gcc to your Windows PATH environment variable.

[Setting environment variables under Windows](http://golang.org/doc/install#windows_env)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and just wanted to add that you specifically need to add the path to the **bin directory** of MinGW to your PATH environment variable. Something like:

`C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0\mingw64\bin`

Not enough reputation to make this a comment, so it's an answer.